# Please rename tag [6to5] to [babeljs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Please rename the tag [6to5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6to5) to [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs). The project recently underwent a name change. The vast majority of online resources (e.g. [official website](https://babeljs.io/), [GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babel), [Gitter](https://gitter.im/babel/babel)) have been changed to reflect this, and updating the tag would make it easier for new/transitioning developers to stay up to track down appropriate documentation.

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) would conflict with the Python library; [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) seems like an appropriate solutions, especially seeing that the official website is https://babeljs.io. It also seems that someone has had this idea and **changed many of the [6to5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6to5) tags to [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) already, meaning that it we may want to cross-reference any [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) tags with [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) to correct the situation**.

At the time of this update, there are 0 questions tagged [6to5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6to5), 10 questions tagged [`babel and ecmascript-6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel+ecmascript-6), and 2 questions tagged [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs).

Comment: There are only 15 questions, you should just manually move them.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild stab and guess that the existing babel tag has nothing to do with babel (formely known as 6to5). Another name would be appropriate. Perhaps babeljs?

Comment: @J.Steen Yes, I only look at the size of the job, and only because I was cleaning up the formatting of the post.  The new tag should probably be [babeljs].

Comment: the babel tag reads `Babel is an integrated collection of utilities that assist in internationalizing and localizing Python applications, with an emphasis on web-based applications. ` Could be renamed to `babel-python`, though.

Comment: Hmm, it seems some has gone through and changed the tags to `babel` anyways, which of course is conflicting the Python babel. I would be in favor of `babeljs`; after all, the official website is https://babeljs.io.

Comment: Looks like this is all set now? [tag:babeljs] has the original 15 questions (plus a new one?) and [tag:babel] still references the Python library

Comment: Sure is @KevinBrown; marked as accepted, seems to be a good solution :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently, the tag wiki for [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) says

> Babel is an integrated collection of utilities that assist in internationalizing and localizing Python applications, with an emphasis on web-based applications.

while the tag wiki for [6to5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6to5) says

> Babel (formerly 6to5) converts ES6 and ES7 code into ES5 code.

So clearly they aren't the exact same thing on Stack Overflow. This is just another example of one project taking over an existing name, but luckily we can fix it before it becomes a problem.

Taking from comments by [J. Steen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286493/please-rename-tag-6to5-to-babel#comment157304_286493) and [njzk2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286493/please-rename-tag-6to5-to-babel#comment157322_286493), I propose that [6to5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6to5) be retagged to [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) and the existing [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) tag is renamed to [babel-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel-python).

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a good solution; as mentioned in comment in the question, we will need another cleanup though, it seems someone has gone through and re-tagged all the `6to5` questions to `babel` without investigating...

Comment: BTW, the question have been updated to reflect this change.